# Solving Inequalities In Programming

Tags: logic, inequality

We are given a variable that have some constraints over its range of value, we have to overall find out a set that denotes it overall range.

For example and conditions are as follows

```
x< 10 
x> -6 
x>= 0
```

I can do it on real number line and mark the intersection but how to do it logically in programming.

Note : Only **> , >= , < , <=** are allowed.

***ANSWER=[0, 10)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to figure out the logic of your solution, then implement that logic in C++. You say you "can do it", which I assume means you find it "easy" to solve as a humain being. What makes it so easy? Identify the method you're using, then write that method in C++.

There are two types of inequalities: > and <. Well, there are also <= and >=, but I suggest leaving those aside until you've written a program that handles < and > correctly.

Imagine you have:

```
x > 5
x > 7
x > 6
x < 11
x < 10
x < 12.
```

What is the solution in this case? Try to find the solution without drawing the number line. Then try to describe with words the way you arrived to this solution.

Then try to write pseudo-code that describes the algorithm more formally.

Finally, you're ready to write C++ code that performs the same steps. I suggest not trying to write C++ until you have written pseudo-code. When writing C++ you'll encounter a few cumbersome details; for instance, how to parse each expression, such as `x < 5`, to find out what inequality it is and which number it's comparing x to. These "details" are not uninteresting but they will get in the way of your logic so it's best to keep them for last.

Comment: Ok but i am trying from2 days i am unable to think how to actually do plsss help me i am honestly speaking i am not getting and ds where i can store

Comment: Did you try finding the solution to `x > 5,
x > 7,
x > 6,
x < 11,
x < 10,
x < 12.` without drawing the number line, like I suggested? If you did and found the solution, can you explain to me how you arrived to this solution?

Comment: Yes for > this i can see we don't need all three conditions we just need x>7 ... While for another we need x<10 ...so i conclude that for > we search largest number and for < we search for smallest number case so finally we get our answer (7,10) ...

Comment: Well done! So that's your algorithm. Keep the largest number in the > bounds and the lowest number in the < bounds.
Now to write de C++ code, all you need to do is read through the lines of input, figure out if the current line is a > or a <, figure out the number, and keep track of the highest > and lowest < numbers encountered so far.

Comment: Thnx i will check out and will tell u if i am finally acc ... By the way i asked 10qn here and all were closed or deleted by me i think my standard is too low :((  this one is also closed ..